How to Handle Asynchronous Initialization in a Dart Object without Blocking Access?
I'm working with a Dart class that requires asynchronous operations to initialize its properties. However, since I cannot use await in the constructor, the object may not be fully initialized when accessed.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
class MyObject {
  late String data;

  MyObject() {
    // Cannot await here
    initialize();
  }

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    data = await fetchData();
    // More initialization logic...
  }

  Future<String> fetchData() async {
    // Simulate an async operation
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    return 'Fetched Data';
  }
}

void build(BuildContext context) {
  MyObject obj = Provider.of<MyObject>(context);
  
  // Accessing data immediately after creation
  print(obj.data); // This may throw an error if 'data' isn't initialized yet
}


Problem:
The build method accesses obj.data immediately after the object is created, which may result in accessing uninitialized data because the initialize method runs asynchronously.
Question:
What is the best way to handle this scenario? How can I ensure that the object is fully initialized before it's accessed, without blocking the construction of the object?
What I tried: I think I can not use a factory constructor here because MyObject is created in a build method using a ChangeNotifierProvider

if it's a future it will have some delay,null-able string or ig you can also use asyncValue for this(riverpod)

tried to play with it but and these are my prefer method of doing it and yes Future will take time

This is part of the problem Riverpod is designed to solve: managing async data (as well as managing data dependencies which might also be async).

@Md.YeasinSheikh MyObject.create and MyObject2.create need to be awaited but as I mentioned, my object is a ChangeNotifier created in a build method, so no await option here too

@RandalSchwartz can you write an answer that shows how Riverpod can help me? It doesn't click when reading the README

"can you write an answer that shows how Riverpod can help me? " see https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/future_provider

Extends class with changenotifier
MyObject extends ChangeNotifier{}

the add new variable call loading
bool loading = true;

then make false after fetching the data
Future<void> initialize() async {
    data = await fetchData();
    loading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  } 

here we calling notifyListeners to update the UI
then the UI should be like
loading is true then show a circularProgressIndicator else show the data
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Consumer<MyObject>(
    builder: (context, myObject, child) {
      if (myObject.isLoading) {
        return CircularProgressIndicator(); // Show loading state
      } else {
        return Text(myObject.data ?? 'No Data'); // Show data once loaded
      }
    },
  );
}

